# What is the particle distribution in Saturn's Ring System?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites

In watching the scientifically scream-inducing film/movie 'Interstellar', there was a shot of the spacecraft moving through the Rings of Saturn. In this shot, and in every graphical representation of the rings I can find, particles of different sizes are nestled together. Can this be the case? Would Newtonian physics not dictate that objects of different masses at the same elevation must travel at different speeds to maintain orbit? Put another way, for the orbit and speed of two objects to be the same, wouldn't their mass (and if made up of similar material, size) be the same as well? If this is the case, wouldn't distribution of particles in the rings be such that any given particle would closely match its neighbours' in size? Or, at least, if a disparity remains in close proximity particle distribution, wouldn't the there be a constant fluidity within the rings as larger particles 'pass' smaller ones?

Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here, or if I'm misinterpreting the basic laws of gravity. But I can't seem to find this question addressed anywhere.

Comment: What law or relationship suggests different massed objects must travel at different (rotational) speeds?

Comment: *"Would Newtonian physics not dictate that objects of different masses at the same elevation must travel at different speeds to maintain orbit?"* It's worth noting that $m_\text{ring object}/m_\text{planet}$ is a very, *very* small number. Why don't you compute the difference in circular orbital velocities between, say 1 gram and 100 kg objects in, say, the F ring. It is an instructive calculation.

Comment: Luckily or otherwise, I haven't seen the film.  But from memory, although **I think** the rings are present only a relatively short time, I was always under the impression that enough time had passed to produce a homogeneous setup,  with most particles being found within a given fairly tight range of mass and size. Just from memory, open to correction on this.

Comment: Although I agree that the difference in circular orbit velocities for the variation of size we're talking about here, as irish physics suggests, we're also talking about the passage of a great deal of time. Are we wrong in assuming that this should translate into a (relatively) 'tight range of mass and size'?